# Возможно ли раздельное написание "не досуг" в значении сказуемого

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

1. В современном словаре слово ***досуг*** определяется как существительное, в отличие от ***недосуг.***

**ДОСУГ**,  м. Время, не занятое работой, делами. Посвятить свой д. театру. В часы досуга заниматься живописью. С пользой провёл свой д. <На досуге, в зн. нареч. В свободное время. Обсудим на досуге.

**НЕДОСУГ**, - м. Разг. Отсутствие свободного времени. Сослаться на н. Объяснять свой отказ недосугом. <**Недосуг (кому). в функц. сказ.** Нет свободного времени у кого-л.; некогда (1.Н.). Ему было н. прочитать статью. Надо бы сходить в библиотеку, да всё н.

2. Но ведь значение сказуемого  для ***досуг*** тоже возможно:  ***Досуг** мне разбирать вины твои, щенок!*
3. Но правила жестко определяют слитое написание ***недосуг*** с функции сказуемого: Розенталь § 61. Частица не с наречиями (пункт 7) http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81

Пункт 7. Частица не пишется раздельно:
2) со словами категории состояния (предикативными наречиями), не соотносительными с прилагательными: не надо, не время, не жаль (но: **недосуг,** неохота и др.);

4. Но почему так? Слова ***досуг/недосуг*** (в значении предикатива) тоже могли бы составить парный вариант со слитным/раздельным написанием.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли ошибка в данных предложениях, нужно исправлять?

*Ты все время в делах, тебе не до женщин, **не досуг!*** [Сергей Осипов. Страсти по Фоме. Книга третья. Книга Перемен (1998)]

З*аканчивай болтать, – оборвал Иосиф. –* *Я не знаю, что это было, но это уже было. И рассуждать, что, как, да почему – **мне не досуг*** (Сергей Гончаров. Билет в никуда, 2022)

А это предложение из обычной речи: ***Не досуг** мне об этом рассуждать.* Оно кажется вполне естественным (логическое выделение отрицания в начале предложения).